# How to add html tag in thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having a "Exception parsing document: template="store/index", line 41 - column 56" , which is this code line below , how do I place the data-content attribute correctly on thymeleaf ?

```
<option value="English" data-content="<img alt='English' src='images/en.jpg'> English">English</option>
```

Comment: Does `data-content="&lt;img alt='English' src='images/en.jpg'&gt; English"` work?  I don't think thymeleaf can handle html tags in attributes like that (so hopefully this works).

Comment: Thank you @Metroids , it worked just fine !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding data-content inside th:attr?

```
th:attr="data-content=..."
```

**Be careful to take care of the quotes(alternating single-double or escape char) when forming the complete element.**